# Is it possible to use only function on "action" in form?

Tags: php

In wordpress's function.php the functions are written to check validate fields, return errors and if no errors, send email.

so in separate page template, it has `<form action="" method="post">` so how to call functions from function.php?

Is it `<form action="form-progress()" method="post">` ?

Any guide or insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Likely it's handling the form submission through javascript.  Though, I don't touch wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually what you can do is this:

```
if(!$_POST) :
echo '
<form method="post" action="[your-same-page]">
[your-form-goes-here]
</form>';
else :
form_progress();
endif;
```

this way, when your user clicks submit, it will enter the else part and check the form.

If you want to verify required fields or something:

```
if(!$_POST || required_fields( $_POST ) != true ) :
echo '
<form method="post" action="[your-same-page]">
[your-form-goes-here]
</form>';
else :
form_progress();
endif;
```

I hope this is what you were asking!

Comment: = thanks! I am trying to make it work. Will return in next few hrs

Answer (score 0):

If your function is in PHP, forget about it.

But if it's in Javascript, just write this code in the tag:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

And in your JS, handle the input values and if you want, you can call an external PHP in AJAX to do other thing like MySQL `INSERT` with values from the form...

Comment: @Freferick Marcoux - thanks for quick response. I see. So function in PHP cannot be passed through the form for validate, and such?

Comment: You can but not directly... You need to set an `action` like `action="my_page.php"` and in your page, manipule the `$_POST` from the form, you can add a `include('functions.php');` and make a simple, `if () {}` statement...